# How do I revert committed lines to become unstaged changes

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

Far more commonly than I care to admit, I will commit some lines/hunks that I didn't intend to.    And I want undo that.

But let's understand what undoing changes I didn't intend to commit means.   It does not mean deleting the changes.   Literally undoing committed line changes mean that there is a commit that removes them, but the changes are retained as "unstaged".

Please do not suggest resetting head because that does NOT accomplish the specific task of undoing "some lines/hunks" (but not others).   Understand that what I'm hoping to do here is a bit more complex than that since it involves a commit that reverts a specific set of changes (but not all changes in that commit), and then redoes those changes, but as unstaged.

I doubt I'm the only person who has ever wanted to do this.

Is there a fairly easy way to do it in git?   How about in SourceTree?

Comment: Does `git reset --soft` not suit your goals? Then you can just stage and commit the specific hunks you want to, but the rest of your changes will not be deleted, they'll merely be unstaged.

Comment: So you just want to unstage the last commit?

Comment: git reset --mixed (default)

Comment: As i mentioned, resetting does not accomplish what I want to accomplish because it fails to meet my requirement of "undoing "sme lines/hunks".   In fact, in fact not only can I not undo specific hunks, i can't even undo specific commits with reset.

Perhaps a specific use case will clarify:   i make commit A, then I make commit B and accidentally include some debug code in the commit.   Then (not yet recognizing my mistake), I commit C on of B.

Now, what to end up with is this:  i want my debugging code removed from HEAD, but IN my index as an an unstaged change.

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR

You probably *should* reset, probably with `--soft`, then use `git checkout -p`, then `git commit`.  That's generally going to be simplest and easiest.  But you don't *have* to do it this way.

A long explanation (with some graph pictures) follows.

#### Why everyone tells you to `git reset`

Once you have made a *commit* with some changes staged, they are *permanently stored that way* in that commit.  Let's back up a lot, because Git doesn't store files the way many people think it does.

For instance, consider this tiny repository with just three commits.  Their actual IDs are some incomprehensible hash strings; for simplicity I've labeled them `A` through `C` instead:

```
A <-B <-C   <-- master
```

The name `master` contains the hash ID of commit `C`.  Commit `C` contains the hash ID of its parent commit `B`, and commit `B` contains the hash ID of its parent commit `A`.  Since `A` is the very first commit (a *root* commit), it has no parent, and Git will stop traversing the history after displaying commit `A`.

We also say that `master` *points to* `C`, `C` points to `B`, and so on.

What's in each of these three commits is a series of *snapshots* of your source.

Making a *new* commit simply means making a commit `D` that points back to `C`, and then changing the name `master` to point to `D`:

```
A <-B <-C <-D   <-- master
```

This new commit is permanent and unchangeable.

Now, each commit *is* a *complete, standalone snapshot* of the entire source.  Commit `D` has every file in exactly the (staged) form it had when you ran `git commit`.  Commit `C` also has every file in exactly the (staged) form it had when you, or whoever, ran the `git commit` that created `C`.  To view `D` as *changes* (from `C`), Git must extract all of `C`, then extract all of `D`, then compare the two to see what's different.

The same holds for what's in your staging area and work-tree right now, except for the fact that these are malleable (not permanent).  That is, the index/staging-area holds a *proposed commit*, and the work-tree holds files you can actually work on (hence the name "work-tree").

When Git tells you that you have staged changes, what Git is doing is comparing what's in your index/staging-area to what's in the current commit, such as commit `D`.  Whatever is different, Git presents as a "staged change".

When Git tells you that you have *un*-staged changes, what Git is doing is comparing what's in your work-tree to what's in your index/staging-area.  Whatever is different, Git presents as an "unstaged change".

Now, let's say you made `D`—your original question suggests that you have done this—but you had more things staged—i.e., copied to the index/staging-area—at the time than you had intended.  Your *permanent* set of stored files in `D` has a form you did not intend.

The index/staging-area, at this point, is quite unchanged from however it was when you ran `git commit`.  So what's in commit `D` matches (exactly) what's in the index/staging-area, which means that nothing is staged for commit.

Since the work-tree is its own separate entity, what's in the *work-tree* right now is still whatever was in it before you made `D`, so the *unstaged* changes are still unstaged.  But the "staged changes" have become a complete snapshot.

This means you need to get rid of commit `D`, and that's where `git reset` comes in.  If you were to somehow do this *and* change *nothing else*, so that the name `master` points to commit `C`, we get this graph:

```
        D   [abandoned]
       /
A--B--C   <-- master
```

Git will now compare what's in `C` to what's in your index/staging-area, and will show you things "staged for commit".  In fact, it will show as staged, exactly what it showed as staged just before you made `D`, because "everything in the index" (the proposed next commit) is what was there *when* you made `D`.

#### You really do want to get rid of this commit

Because commits are unchangeable, if you leave `D` in place and add more commits, you'll have, in your repository history, this unwanted snapshot.  So you *do* have to discard it—but you don't necessarily have to do this with `git reset`.  It may be *easier* if you do, though.

(Everywhere I say "have to", it is of course optional.  If you want, you can leave the useless / bad / negative-value `D` commit in place.  But I suspect you don't intend to.)

#### Changing that which is staged

Now let's look at making some changes become *un*staged.

Suppose you do this reset, which is actually `git reset --soft HEAD^` or `git reset --soft HEAD~1`.  This tells Git to move `master` back one step, without touching the index/staging-area, and without touching the work-tree.  Now you can use `git checkout -p -- <path>`, as in [AnimiVulpis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46777654/1256452).  This will let you apply small changes to the copies of files in the index.

If you *didn't* do the `git reset`, you could still run `git checkout -p`, but you'd want to add the hash ID of commit `C`, or some way to tell Git to look inside commit `C`.  That could be as simple as `git checkout -p HEAD^ <path>`.

If you do either of these `git checkout -p` commands (with or without the initial `git reset --soft`), you can get the copy of the file in the index to have the form you want.  It's very hard to tell *whether* it has the form you want, though, because you *cannot view the version of the file that is in the index*.

#### Viewing what's in the index

To see what's in the index, you would normally run `git diff --cached` (to compare `HEAD` to index/staging-area) or `git diff` (to compare index to work-tree).  This doesn't show you the contents directly; instead, it shows you how those contents *differ from* the contents of `HEAD`—which you probably know about—or from the contents of the work-tree, which you *can* see.

These, again, are the "staged changes" (contents of index as compared to contents of `HEAD` commit), or the "unstaged changes" (contents of work-tree as compared to contents index).  But they're in relation to the `HEAD` commit.  If you *haven't* run `git reset` yet, you have to take care to add "commit `C` vs `commit`D`" to any changes shown as "commit`D` vs index".

So this is why you really might want to start with `git reset --soft`.

#### The default for `git reset` is `--mixed`

If you run `git reset HEAD^`, without `--soft`, Git will *wipe out* (reset) your current index/staging-area, replacing it wholesale with the contents of the previous commit.

Git won't touch the work-tree, so if you had carefully built the index from the work-tree, you can re-do all that work now.  But if that was a lot of work, you probably *don't* want to do a `--mixed` reset.

Still, it's an option, and something useful to remember if you accidentally (or in desperation) run a `--mixed` or default `git reset`.

#### Once you have the index arranged, you can commit

Once you have the index/staging-area set up the way you want, *now* you can make the commit you intended to make all along.

If you've left commit `D` in place, so that the commit graph is:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

you can run `git commit --amend` instead of a regular `git commit`.  What this does is to make your new commit `E`, and point `master` to it, almost in the normal way—except for one thing: the new commit `E` will have, as its parent, commit `C`.  This has the effect of shoving `D` up to the side and abandoning it:

```
        D   [abandoned]
       /
A--B--C--E   <-- master
```

But if you did a `git reset` earlier—whether `--soft` or the default `--mixed`—then you already *have* commit `D` shoved up to the side and abandoned, so you can just add commit `E` in the usual way.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you are looking for the `-p` of [`git checkout -p`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout---patch) which lets you

> Interactively select hunks in the difference between the `<tree-ish>` (or the index, if unspecified) and the working tree

Answer (score 0):

Viable solution: **Reverse hunk**?

Beware of the **SourceTree** and **GitKraken** reverse hunk bugs...they had bugs where the entire file would be reversed if you tried to just reverse a hunk. I see GitKraken patched it on the 9th October 2017 with version 3.1.1. but I don't know about the state of SourceTree.